# Xcode 11 "iphone is busy: Making iphone ready for development"

Tags: ios

I have been waiting 2 days now, and the xcode "Devices and simulators" window is still hung with the message "myiphone is busy: Making myiphone ready for development".

1. I have connected this phone to xcode and uploaded apps many times before
2. I have not updated ios nor macos recently

I have tried the usual suspects:

1. waiting. 5 hours so far.
2. disconnecting phone, restarting xcode
3. rebooting phone.
4. rebooting mac
5. checking under general-device management, nothing new there.

versions:

- xcode 11.2
- 2017 mb pro 512 quad. 16GB
- mac 10.14.4 (I can never upgrade beyond this due to need for 32bit drivers).
- ios 13.3.1
- iphone storage: 51GB
  of 64GB used.

I also frequently get the issue that when I connect the iphone the device managers says its locked, but it is not locked. In this case, I disconnect device, restart xcode, reconnect the device while xcode is running, which fixes this common issue.

Comment: i had this issues until i turn off bluetooth to disconnect from my watch, it got stuck because of the Apple watch sync or whatever

Comment: Had the same problem with iPhone running iOS 16.4 with any of Xcode 14.2, 14.3 and 15.  Tried all of the current answers with no success. Finally what worked was upgrading the phone to 16.7

Answer (score 5):

In devices manager click unpair as shown in this screenshot.

[image]

Then in your iphone click trust and the issue is gone.

Comment: BTW this window is found in the menu bar at the top Window > Devices and Simulators. This worked for me.

Answer (score 4):

Oh my, that is weird! And annoying. I had the same before, here is what I tried, in addition to your things:

- Clean Build
- Wiggle the cable (or use different port, one was faulty)
- Try buiding via wifi instead of cable
- Remove the phone from device-manager and "trust" it again

Answer (score 0):

Well, some days later, after several reboots and assorted activities, it started working.  So no idea what caused it.

Comment: That’s great that you got it going. But “no idea” is not an answer.

Comment: By the way if you plan to submit apps to the App Store you will need a partition with Catalina installed on it.

Comment: hey, have you found the solution yet?? I am facing the same problem as you.

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't used the device in a while and the battery was empty, check if the system time has been reset to 1970.

This causes all kinds of issues, among them wifi may not work.

XCode does not give any indication of this possible issue, just stays stuck on preparing device...